Swift UI wait for loading of data from API before setupUI
I have set up a navigationlist which successfully displays a model type array of data, only issue is when loading data from API the content tries to load to view before data is ready. mob solution below errors due to UIHostingController not being run on main thread?
func getGenres(_ completion: @escaping (CompetitionGroup?) -> ()) {

        let headers = [
            "x-rapidapi-key": "api-key***",
            "x-rapidapi-host": "football-web-pages1.p.rapidapi.com"
        ]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://football-web-pages1.p.rapidapi.com/competitions.json?include=rounds")! as URL,
                                                cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                            timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error as Any)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let comps = try decoder.decode(CompetitionGroup.self, from: data!)
                    self.competitions = comps
                    completion(self.competitions)
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error in JSON")
                }
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }

Called in SetupUI():
private func setupUI() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapLogout))
        
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        
        getGenres { (array) in
            // Do operation with array
            competitionslist =  array
            let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()) // ERROR HERE
            self.addChild(childView)
            childView.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(childView.view)
            childView.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
        //competitionslist =  getComps()                        
        
    }

Have tried various things that helped others from Stack Overflow but no joy, this one at least builds.
Below is my ContentView navigation list setup, I don't understand how to load the data before this starts executing, competitionlist errors as it is nil:
struct ContentView: View {
    let compse = competitionslist
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(compse!.competitions, id: \.id) { competition in
                                NavigationLink(destination: Text(competition.genericname ?? "")) {
                                    Image(systemName: "airplane")
                                    Text(competition.genericname ?? "")
                                }.padding()
                
                }
                .navigationTitle("Leagues")
            }
        }
    }
}


You need to dispatch your completion handler onto the main queue because the network operation executes on a different queue

How do I do this, the below answer does not help @Paulw11

Set up the view before you start loading data.
Change the view to display the data after data loading completion.
private func setupUI() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapLogout))
    
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
    ])
    
    let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        self.addChild(childView)
        childView.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(childView.view)
        childView.didMove(toParent: self)
}

private fund loadData() {
       //load data here
       // present the data in childView
}


Hi how do I present the data in child view I don't understand?
